# Lookup word in data frame, return column name?

Tags: r, dplyr

I wish to search a dataframe (really, a categorized word list), and if the word is found, it returns the column name; if it is not found, it simply reproduces the word. The basic idea is below but I can't get it to work as expected:

```
#data frame to be searched
words <- data.frame(people=c("Mike", "Tom", "Molly", "Susan"),
           dogs=c("Rex", "Fido", "King", "Roy"))

#data frame to work with
d <- data.frame(name=c("Roy","Tom", "Pat"))

d %>% mutate(
  returned = ifelse(name %in% d, colnames(), name)
)
```

This returns:

```
  name returned
1  Roy        2
2  Tom        3
3  Pat        1
```

However, it should return

```
  name returned
1  Roy        dog
2  Tom        people
3  Pat        Pat
```

I feel like my script is close, but not sure what to do to fix it.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers in the 'returned' are due to the `factor` coercion to `integer` storage mode values.  It can be avoided if we create a `character` class column with  `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` while creating the data.frame or use `as.character(name)`.

```
d <- data.frame(name=c("Roy","Tom", "Pat"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
words <- data.frame(people=c("Mike", "Tom", "Molly", "Susan"),
       dogs=c("Rex", "Fido", "King", "Roy"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

In addition to the issue with `factor`, the OP's code in `ifelse` is not using the keyvalue dataset 'words' i.e. `name %in% d` refers to calling the value of column 'name' in the data.frame, and the second argument is `colnames()`,  which would have resulted in 'error', but because the first expression is returning `FALSE`, it will check the 'no' values i.e' 'name'

```
d %>%
    mutate(i1 =  name %in% d)
#  name    i1
#1  Roy FALSE
#2  Tom FALSE
#3  Pat FALSE
```

Because the 'name' is `factor`, its values are coerced to integer mode and that is what is showed in the output

---

We can use `pivot_longer` to convert to 'long' format and then do a `right_join`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
words %>%
     pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
     right_join(d, by = c('value' = 'name')) %>%
     mutate(name = ifelse(is.na(name), value, name)) %>%
     select(returned = name, name = value)
#   returned name
#1     dogs  Roy
#2   people  Tom
#3      Pat  Pat
```

---

Or we can use `case_when` without any reshaping

```
d %>%
   mutate(returned = case_when(name %in% words$people ~ 'people',
                      name %in% words$dogs ~ 'dogs', 
                      TRUE ~ as.character(name)))
#   name returned
#1  Roy     dogs
#2  Tom   people
#3  Pat      Pat
```

---

Or using only `base R`

```
d$returned <- with(stack(words), as.character(ind[match(d$name, values)]))
d$returned[is.na(d$returned)] <- d$name[is.na(d$returned)]
d
#  name returned
#1  Roy     dogs
#2  Tom   people
#3  Pat      Pat
```

Comment: The right join will work perfectly for my needs. I thought about case_when, but the words list will contain many columns, so that wouldn't be practical.

Answer (score 2):

We can get `words` data in long format and then do a `left_join`. For the returned values that do not match we can replace with `name` value.

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
  left_join(tidyr::pivot_longer(words, cols = names(words), names_to = 'returned'), 
            by = c('name' = 'value')) %>%
  mutate(returned = coalesce(returned, name))

#  name returned
#1  Roy     dogs
#2  Tom   people
#3  Pat      Pat
```